# Python script throws an exception when I try to list the file size

Tags: python, windows, scripting, operating-system

I'm developing a Python script that captures all `.DLL` files from the windows system32 folder, I can list all `.dll` files without problems, but when I try to list the file size in MB it inexplicably falls into an exception.

code:

```py
import os

PATH = 'c:\\Windows\\system32\\'

def System32(file_path):
    sys32 = os.listdir(file_path)
    for file in sys32:
        if '.dll' in file:
            yield file

path_sys32 = System32(PATH)

for size_file in path_sys32:
    name = size_file
    size = os.path.getsize(size_file) / 1000000
    print(f'Name: {name} > {size:.2f} MB')
```

exception:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vinny\Desktop\scripts\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    size = os.path.getsize(size_file) / 1000000
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen genericpath>", line 50, in getsize
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado: '69fe178f-26e7-43a9-aa7d-2b616b672dde_eventlogservice.dll'
```

**OBS:** When the `listdir()` method is empty, the script works perfectly, but when you pass a `path` to it, it falls into this exception.

code:

```py
import os

def System32():
    sys32 = os.listdir()
    for file in sys32:
        if '.dll' in file:
            yield file

path_sys32 = System32()

for size_file in path_sys32:
    name = size_file
    size = os.path.getsize(size_file) / 1000000
    print(f'Name: {name} > {size:.2f} MB')
```

- This Code above works perfectly without passing anything to the `listdir()` method, basically for this to work, the code needs to be in system32.

Could this be a bug in the `os` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `os.listdir()` command returns the *names* of the files only, not their full *paths* (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)). So, if you are inside the `system32` folder, your code will work: in this special case, the names of the files are the same as their relative paths and they are found.

In all other cases, you need to concatenate the `os.listdir()` results with your folder path, so as to get the full file paths, so that they later can be found by `getsize()`. The following should work:

```py
def System32(file_path):
    sys32 = os.listdir(file_path)
    for file in sys32:
        if '.dll' in file:
            # Append file name to folder path, then yield result
            yield os.path.join(file_path, file)
```

Alternatively, you can use `join()` later, namely directly in `getsize()` (i.e. `os.path.getsize(os.path.join(PATH, size_file))`). In this way, your `name` in the last line will still print correctly (i.e. only the file name and not its full path).

As a side note, the error message (which, if I got this correctly, translates as *The system cannot find the specified file*) already gives you a clue: It only shows you the name of the file that is not found, not its path. (Admittedly, this may seem helpful only in hindsight.)